# have rsync handle individual files with single quote in them

Tags: linux, rsync

I am sync-ing up a directory that has a bunch of documents in it.  Users that input documents with all manner of weird characters in their file names.  I need to sync up these files from one location on Linux to another.  Many times only a single file needs to be updated.  When the file name contains a single quote it croaks.  I need to specify user@server for the destination, otherwise it works.  For example:

```
rsync --rsh=ssh "zz/joe's change.txt" "/somedir/y/joe's change.txt"
```

works.

```
rsync --rsh=ssh "zz/joe's change.txt" user@server:"/somedir/y/"
```

also works.

But the form I wish to use:

```
rsync --rsh=ssh "zz/joe's change.txt" user@server:"/somedir/y/joe's change.txt"
```

fails with:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes read so far)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(165)
```

I could use the second form (unless some nut puts a ' in the directory name), but really want to use the third form.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, what finally worked for me was to use the `--protect-args` or `-s` argument, and then taking the whole thing under quotes as follows:

```
rsync -s --rsh=ssh "zz/joe's change.txt" "user@server:/somedir/y/joe's change.txt"
```

Note that even the remote `server` and `user` are also under the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to escape that character. From bash man page

> A non-quoted backslash (\) is the
>   escape character. It preserves the
>   literal value of the next character
>   that follows, with the exception of
>   <newline>.

Answer (score 0):

Gleb put me on the right track.  I had tried escaping inside the quotes (along with other variations on quoting and escaping the destination) and that did not work.

I have now gone back and found it will work by double escaping the destination:

```
rsync --rsh=ssh "zz/joe's change.txt" user@server:/somedir/y/joe\\\'s\\\ change.txt
```

or

```
rsync --rsh=ssh zz/joe\'s\ change.txt user@server:/somedir/y/joe\\\'s\\\ change.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rsync --rsh=ssh "zz/joe's change.txt" "user@server:/somedir/y/joe's change.txt"
```

The " is a signal to the shell and it may not work as part of an argument.